# Best design pattern to handle Task Results ( await / async )

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task

I have just installed Visual Studio 2012, So I can finally test C# 5.0 features
like async/await. I was doing some testing and a doubt come to my mind. 
What is the best way to handle task Results.

Given the following Snippet:

```
Task<List<string>> tarea = GetStringListAsync();
 tarea.ContinueWith((x) =>
  {
                if (x.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
                {
                    x.Result.ForEach((y) => Console.WriteLine(y));
                }
                else if (x.Status == TaskStatus.Faulted)

                {
                    Console.WriteLine(x.Exception.InnerException.Message);
                }
  });


 private static async Task<List<string>> GetStringListAsync()
        {
            return await Task.Run(() =>
            {
               return  GetStringList();
            });

        }

        private static List<string> GetStringList()
        {
            //I uncomment this to get forced exception  
            //throw new Exception("Error Occurred");

            //Add some delay
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(12000);
            return new List<string>() { "String1", "String2", "String3" };

        }
```

I am handling the task Result in `ContinueWith` , but I would like to know if there is a **better** aproach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `await` instead of `ContinueWith` or `Result`:

```
try
{
  List<string> area = await GetStringListAsync();
  area.ForEach((y) => Console.WriteLine(y));
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

As a side note, you [should usually not wrap synchronous methods (`GetStringList`) with a fake-asynchronous methods](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx) (e.g., using `Task.Run`). Let the caller decide if they want to push it to a background thread:

```
try
{
  List<string> area = await Task.Run(() => GetStringList());
  area.ForEach((y) => Console.WriteLine(y));
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Using     List<string> result = await GetStringListAsync();
tell me await operator can only be used with async method. I cant understand why since it is async method.

Comment: It's talking about the code that has the `await` in it. *That* method also needs to be `async`. Yes, this will cause a "chain reaction" as `async` grows through your code base.

Comment: I found my final doubt in a stackoverflow question that you answered as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11836325/await-operator-can-only-be-used-within-an-async-method. Thanks you very much for your help dude.

Comment: Main cannot be `async`. You have a couple of options: you can install a SynchronizationContext [(described on my blog)](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-console-programs.html) or you can create an `async Task MainAsync` method and synchronously block on it from `Main`: `MainAsync().Wait();`

Comment: You are a Master! Thanks again. Will take a look at your blog periodically.