# Assembly error using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, xpath, reference, html-agility-pack, windows-phone-8.1

I want to create an app that takes something from a web page and that shows it to the user. In order to do this thing, i used HtmlAgilityPack. I added the reference to the project (v. 1.4.6.0 from NuGet) and i used the code that a user posted in another question some years ago.

```
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            // There are various options, set as needed
            htmlDoc.OptionFixNestedTags = true;

            // filePath is a path to a file containing the html
            htmlDoc.Load(filePath);
            if (htmlDoc.ParseErrors != null && htmlDoc.ParseErrors.Count() > 0)
            {
                // Handle any parse errors as required
            }
            else
            {
                if (htmlDoc.DocumentNode != null)
                {
                    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode bodyNode = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body");

                    if (bodyNode != null)
                    {
                        // Do something with bodyNode
                    }
                }
            }
```

My problem is that i get the following error:

> The type 'System.Xml.XPath.IXPathNavigable' is defined in an assembly
>   that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'System.Xml.XPath, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

So i tried to add the reference using the following dll:

> c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Silverlight\v5.0\Libraries\Client\System.Xml.XPath.dll

But this time i get the following error (i translated it because i get an italian error, so it may not be the correct translation):

> It is not possible to add a reference to an assembly to the project that
>   is not compatible or of an above version

What can i do?

Comment: Is this windows phone 8.1 silverlight apps or windows phone store apps?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that HtmlAgilityPack (HAP) for windows phone 8.1 store apps doesn't support XPath, similar to [HAP for Windows 8 store apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23190591/htmlagilitypack-in-windows-store-app).

In this case, you can use LINQ API of HAP instead of XPath API, for example :

```
......
if (htmlDoc.DocumentNode != null)
{
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode bodyNode = doc.DocumentNode
                                           .DescendantsAndSelf("body")
                                           .FirstOrDefault();
    if (bodyNode != null)
    {
        // Do something with bodyNode
    }
}
......
```

Even if you actually have windows phone silverlight apps project, LINQ API is still a possible workaround.