# HtmlAgilityPack using Linq for windows phone 8.1 platform

Tags: c#, linq, html-agility-pack, windows-phone-8.1

As HtmlAgilityPack is yet not supported in windows phone 8.1,referencing manually in the project was a trick solution. But this is not the only problem. I could use `XPath` for my past project to select nodes. Now I can see that `HtmlDocumentNode.SelectNode()` function is no more(because of version compatibility may be).

what I used in my past project was similar to this

```
HtmlNode parent = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//ul[@class='songs-list1']");
HtmlNodeCollection x = parent.ChildNodes;
```

I searched over stackoverflow and google and got an Idea that It's still possible to select nodes using Linq.

I'm seeking for a block of code which will work like `SelectNodes`, `SelectNode`.

Loading the `HtmlDocument` asynchronously would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you meant to translate your current code which using XPath to be using LINQ, then this will do :

```
HtmlNode parent = document.DocumentNode
                          .Descendants("ul")
                          .FirstOrDefault(o => o.GetAttributeValue("class", "") 
                                                   == "songs-list1")
HtmlNodeCollection x = parent.ChildNodes;
```

But if you expect to find methods that accept XPath in HtmlAgilityPack version for Windows Phone 8.1 universal apps or Windows RT ("*I'm seeking for a block of code which will work like `SelectNodes`, `SelectNode`*"), you better don't : [HtmlAgilityPack & Windows 8 Metro Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15941529/htmlagilitypack-windows-8-metro-apps) (answer by the author of HAP).

Comment: What is `null`? `parent` is null? Try to save your `HtmlDocument` and see if it actually has `<ul>` with such `class` attribute.

Comment: yes parent is null. I'm sure about about the node and it's class name.

Comment: Please check/debug. Don't guess coz I'm also sure about this code, even worked fine when I tested using simple HTML containing `<ul class="songs-list1">`. Or post your HTML so we can confirm whether this code works or not.

Comment: okay, basically I'm trying to parse this website http://www.songspk.name/
and trying to get the list of album updates portion. please check it yourself.

Comment: just for your reference I used this 2 lines of code to get the "HTML DOCUMENT"

HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();
            document.LoadHtml(latestNewsUrl);

Comment: okay, that's need to be fixed. `LoadHtml()` accept html string (`<html>....</html>`) instead of URL. Check if `HtmlWeb` is available for you, check discussion in comment for how to use `HtmlWeb` : http://stackoverflow.com/a/23190899/2998271

Comment: Now I get the following error "Type Access Exception " when I used this two lines of code. HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb(); HtmlDocument document = await web.LoadFromWebAsync(latesturl);

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the Element/s method:

```
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(htmlString);
        var h6Nodes = from h6element in doc.DocumentNode.Element("body").Element("center").Elements("h6")
                      where h6element.Attributes["class"].Value.Equals("songs-list")                      
                      select h6element;
```

This is assuming you have something like

```
string htmlString = @"<html>
<body>
<center>
<h6>Hello  </h6>
<h6>World!   </h6>
<h6 class=""songs-list"">
Insert that one song here
</h6>
</center>
</body>
</html>"
```

and that will get the `<h6>` node with class songs-list.

Comment: can you please tell what "body" and "center" parameter does?

Comment: Those are just example tags! In your case, it would be Elements("ul")