# Htmlagilitypack Windows Phone 8.0 Node selection and conditional statements

Tags: xaml, xpath, windows-phone-8, html-agility-pack

I'm having issues with extracting data from the below html code, for use in a Windows Phone 8.0 Silverlight app using htmlagilitypack.

What I want to do is have the div 'game white-c' as the starting point for my node selection.

I was trying to use

`foreach (var div in htmlDocumentLive.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class, 'game white-c')]"))`

But this doesn't work.

Additionally, sometimes only Game3 may be available so I would need a conditional statement such as `position() = 3`. Other times, maybe Game1 and Game4 will be available. So I would need it to firstly check for all games. If any are unavailable i.e. contain no data, the code would then attempt to go through each game and try to load it before moving onto the next.

```
<section class="gamelist">
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="vc gamessection">
            <div class="col-1-4">
                <h2 class="white-c">Get free games</h2>
            </div> 
            <div class="col-3-4">
                <!-- GAME -->
                <div class="game white-c">
                    <div class="boxshot">
                    <img class="boximg" alt="Game1" src="https://images.com" title="Game1">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- END GAME -->

                <!-- GAME -->
                <div class="game white-c">
                    <div class="boxshot">
                    <img class="boximg" alt="Game2" src="https://images.com" title="Game2">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- END GAME -->

                <!-- GAME -->
                <div class="game white-c">
                    <div class="boxshot">
                    <img class="boximg" alt="Game3" src="https://images.com" title="Game3">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- END GAME -->

                <!-- GAME -->
                <div class="game white-c">
                    <div class="boxshot">
                    <img class="boximg" alt="Game4" src="https://images.com" title="Game4">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- END GAME -->

                <!-- GAME -->
                <div class="game white-c">
                    <div class="boxshot">
                    <img class="boximg" alt="Game5" src="https://images.com" title="Game5">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- END GAME -->
            </div>           
        </div> 
    </div>
</section>
```

Thanks.

Comment: The HTML is malformed.

Comment: The HTML is from a third party website, of which I removed excess as it wasn't needed for this purpose. However, I have edited it again. Thanks.

Comment: @kkerswell AFAIK, HAP version for windows phone doesn't support XPath : http://stackoverflow.com/a/25262371/2998271

Comment: @har07 Thanks, that is true of standard 8.1 Windows Phone apps.  But I have been, and am using 8.0 Windows Phone Silverlight - where HAP does work.