# 'await' operator can only be used within an async method with c# exception?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am using hellosign c# api and when I am calling function for account info using below code

```
var helloSign = new HelloSignClient("username", "password");
    Account account = await helloSign.Account.GetAsync();
    Console.WriteLine("Your current callback: " + account.CallbackUrl);
```

I am getting below error.

```
Error    2    The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.
```

below is GetAsync method

```
public async Task<Account> GetAsync()
        {
            AccountWrapper accountWrapper = await helloSignService.MakeRequestAsync<AccountWrapper>(settings.HelloSignSettings.Endpoints.Account.Get);
            return accountWrapper.Account;
        }
```

this is type of account class

```
public class Account : AccountCondensedWithRole
    {
        [JsonProperty("callback_url")]
        public string CallbackUrl { get; internal set; }
    }
```

Can some one tell me how to call this or how to debug this ???

Comment: did that signature change recently - could you try a clean build?

Comment: @DanielA.White i already did rebuilt.. but not working ... so i thought of posting it ..

Comment: @DanielA.White what does signature change recently means ...???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should wrap this block in Async Method like this

```
public async Task<Type> MethodAsync(){
    // other code if needed ....
    var helloSign = new HelloSignClient("username", "password");
    Account account = await helloSign.Account.GetAsync();
    Console.WriteLine("Your current callback: " + account.CallbackUrl);
    return type;

}
```

Comment: How should I call inside main method, if I want to some return type.. How can i do that can u please explain it to me ??

Answer (score 3):

The message is pretty clear. This line must be inside a method marked with `async`:

```
Account account = await helloSign.Account.GetAsync();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can only use await in an async method.

Here's another question to the same problem [await operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11836325/await-operator-can-only-be-used-within-an-async-method)