# Cannot use await with my instance of UserManager

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to extract the selected user using an instance of UserManager, in order to display details about a particular user in a view. I am trying to use the following line of code:

```
var user = await _userManager.Users.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
```

However, this gives the following error:

"The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method."

I'm really confused, because surely the SingleOrDefaultAsync method is an async method - the clue is in the name! It even says 'awaitable' when I hover my mouse over it, so why can't I use the 'await' keyword in this situation?

I've tried just taking out the 'await' keyword, and it will then compile but if I try to access the View, I get the following error:

InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[MyProject.Models.ApplicationUser]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'MyProject.Models.ApplicationUser'.

For context, here is my controller method:

```
    //
    // GET /Account/Details/5
    public IActionResult Details(string id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var user = _userManager.Users.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);

        if (user == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(user);
    }
```

and here is what my View is expecting:

```
@model ApplicationUser
```

Any help is much appreciated, and apologies if this is a very easy thing that I'm struggling on, I'm still very much a beginner with .Net and MVC!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Await operator can only be used within an Async method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11836325/await-operator-can-only-be-used-within-an-async-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your action method `async`. It should now return `Task<IActionResult>` instead of `IActionResult`

Now you can await an async method inside that

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(string id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var user = await _userManager.Users.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);

    if (user == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return View(user);
}
```

> InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the
>   ViewDataDictionary is of type
>   'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[MyProject.Models.ApplicationUser]', but
>   this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type
>   'MyProject.Models.ApplicationUser'

You get the above exception when you call the async method without the `await` keyword. When you execute the below code,

`var user = _userManager.Users.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);`

Here user is of type `Task<User>`, not `User`. But your view is strongly typed to `User` and expects a `User` object but you are trying to pass a Task.  That is why you are getting the exception.

Comment: Thank you! That makes perfect sense now, I was completely mis-interpreting the error I was getting.